# How do I check out a particular version in Git from 'git log'?

Tags: linux, git

My `git log` is showing something as:

```
enter code here
[git_trial]$ git log
commit 4c5bc66ae50780cf8dcaf032da98422aea6e2cf7
Author: king <king@king.ap.com>
Date:   Thu Jun 30 15:09:55 2011 +0530


This is third commit

commit 8072be67ddd310bc200cab0dccb8bcb2ec4f922c

Author: king <king@king.ap.com>

Date:   Thu Jun 30 14:17:27 2011 +0530

This is the second commit

commit 3ba6ce43d500b12f64368b2c27f35211cf189b68

Author: king <king@king.ap.com>

Date:   Thu Jun 30 14:00:01 2011 +0530


This is the first git commit for file1
```

Question 1: Now, how do I check out only my first version?

Question 2: Also, when I do `git log` on only File1, why does it show only the first commit?

```
 [git_trial]$ git checkout 3ba6ce43d500b12f64368b2c27f35211cf189b68
 Note: moving to "3ba6ce43d500b12f64368b2c27f35211cf189b68" which isn't a local branch
 If you want to create a new branch from this checkout, you may do so
 (now or later) by using -b with the checkout command again. Example:

  git checkout -b <new_branch_name>


  [git_trial]$ git log File1

  commit 3ba6ce43d500b12f64368b2c27f35211cf189b68

  Author: king <king@king.ap.com>
  Date:   Thu Jun 30 14:00:01 2011 +0530

  This is the first git commit for file1
```

Answer (score 68, accepted):

You can checkout a commit using `git checkout sha-of-commit` which you already have.

But you cannot commit anything (as you're not in a branch, you're in a static commit).

If you need to commit anything on top of that commit, you need to check it out into a branch using `git checkout sha-of-commit -b testing-a-commit`.

`git log <file>` only shows commits that affect that file.

Comment: Sorry for the late response..net is too slow here. So you mean, if i create a branch then do my first and successive commits, then i can checkout any particular version?

Comment: @kingshasher1, sha = SHA1 hash, like `3ba6ce43d500b12f64368b2c27f35211cf189b68`.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here? Why do you want to check out a commit? Just to read, or to commit something on top of it?

Comment: If you just want to read the source, `git checkout <sha>` would work fine.