# How can I Clone previous version of repo in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

As the heading states, How can I clone previous version of project from Github on **ANDROID STUDIO**?

Edit: On linux machine or using Terminal I can restore previous version but I want specific answers to Android Studio. Please don't flag it duplicate as it is a different question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to checkout a particular version in git from git log?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6533222/how-to-checkout-a-particular-version-in-git-from-git-log)

Comment: Not on linux or using terminal , I am asking on Android studio. From the platform itself.

Comment: You can just open the VCS window and Checkout a specific commit